# C - Pointer - Array - Realloc -Malloc - Prime numbers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am new in C. The code below does not work. I don't understand why it isn't working. can you help? Thanks...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int array_size=4;
    int *prime_number=(int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
    int *square_rt,*add_oz;
    int limitL=100;
    prime_number[0]=2;
    prime_number[1]=3;
    prime_number[2]=5;
    prime_number[3]=7;
    for (int i=9;i<limitL;i+=2){
        *add_oz=1;
        *square_rt=sqrt(i);
        for (int a=0;a<array_size;a++){
            if (*square_rt>=prime_number[a]){
                if (i%prime_number[a]==0){
                    *add_oz=0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else{
                break;
            }   
        }
        if (add_oz){
            prime_number=realloc(prime_number, (array_size+1)*sizeof(int)  );
            prime_number[array_size]=i;
            ++array_size;
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I take a Segmentation fault error.

s

Comment: what is the value of `square_rt` and `add_oz`? (They are pointer variables, so their value is the address of a different variable - which variable?)

Comment: Some of your pointers doesn't point anywhere, yet you dereference them. That leads to *undefined behavior*. And *why* is e.g. `add_oz` a pointer? Especially considering the mixed usage of it (as a pointer and as a non-pointer value).

Comment: add_oz is boolean variable.I used most of them as pointers because I wanted to understand pointers. And,  I defined squara_rt and add_oz as integer values, but I got the error  "realloc (): invalid next size"

Comment: In `if (add_oz)` you don't use it as a pointer, but as an actual value. And you never make these pointers actually *point* somewhere! Pointer must point somewhere before you can dereference them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should check the return value of `re-m(alloc)`.
Next, you should `free` the memory dinamically allocated.
Your code has pointers that doesn't point anywhere.

With `math.h` maybe you have to compile with `-lm`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    int array_size = 4, square_rt, add_oz, limitL = 100;
    int *prime_number = malloc(sizeof(int)*4);
    if (prime_number == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to find free memory\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    prime_number[0] = 2;
    prime_number[1] = 3;
    prime_number[2] = 5;
    prime_number[3] = 7;
    for (int i = 9; i < limitL; i += 2) {
        add_oz = 1;
        square_rt = sqrt(i);
        for (int a = 0; a < array_size; a++) {
            if (square_rt >= prime_number[a]) {
                if (i%prime_number[a] == 0) {
                    add_oz = 0;
                    break;
                }
            } else {
                break;
            }   
        }
        if (add_oz) {
            prime_number = realloc(prime_number, (array_size+1)*sizeof(int));
            if (prime_number == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Unable to realloc memory\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            prime_number[array_size] = i;
            ++array_size;
        }
    }
    free(prime_number);
    return 0;
}
```

Learn to indent because is easier to other people to read your code and for you too.

Comment: Thanks, it is worked . can I ask you a few questions?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: if (prime_number==NULL)  -->  why did we put this condition.what is the difference between  malloc(sizeof(int)*4); and (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*4);

Comment: 1. If you read the manual, malloc return the pointer to the first memory byte allocated but it can also fail, and if fail to alloc memory it return NULL. We want to kill the program if malloc is unable to find free memory.

2. In the second malloc you are casting the result to int, but we know it is int, so imho you don't need to cast it, but is the same, is not an error.

Comment: when is memory allocation fail? How realloc works? for example: memory is==|5|--|2|--|11|--|100|--|empty|--|empty|    `int a[3]={5,2,11};  int b=100;` I want to add a new value to the a and I use realloc .what will happen to the list after using the memory. 1- |5|--|2|-|11|-|new_value|-|100|--|empty|     2- |5|--|2|--|11|--|100|--|new_value|-|empty| . End thanks for everything.

Comment: It is very difficult for them to fail but this can happen for example when you do not have enough memory space to hold a certain contiguous memory space.